# Composite type in mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I'm trying to create a Mongoose Schema for a type "comment", which has inside "text" ,"time", "user" fields but also an array of "comments" meaning the answers for that comments. How can you specify that the type of the array of that field in comment is also a comment. I leave you some code about what I'm trying to do. Alternatives are also well received (apart from just storing in the array the id of the answers, that's a pretty rough solution). Thank you so much

```
const CommentSchema = new Schema({
    text: { type: String, required: false },
    timestamp: { type: Date, required: true, default: Date.now },
    user: { type: String, required: true },
    answer: [ CommentSchema.schema ],
    liked: [ String ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this? I think it should work

```
const CommentSchema = new Schema({
    text: { type: String, required: false },
    timestamp: { type: Date, required: true, default: Date.now },
    user: { type: String, required: true },
    answer: {
      type: [CommentSchema],
      default: []
    },
    liked: [ String ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You try this blow schema (or) you read the [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html) ones.

```
const answersCommentsSchema = new Schema({
 text: { type: String, default : null },
    user: { type: String, required: true },
},{timestamps : true});

const CommentSchema = new Schema({
    text: { type: String, default : null },
    user: { type: String, required: true },
    answer: [answersCommentsSchema],
    liked: {type : Array, default:[]}
},{timestamps : true});
```